# Where is the instance of a WCF object stored?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm going to be creating a service that needs to make a call to a hosted WCF service halfway around the world. This isn't that big of a deal since the number of transactions that will be made is relatively low. However, I need to pass in an instance of a class that will possibly be defined in the WCF to the necessary WCF function.

So my question is, will that instance of the class exist on my server? Or will I be contacting the host server every time I attempt to set a variable in the object?

EXAMPLE:`

```
   public class Dog
{
    public string noise;
    public int numLegs;
}

public class doSomething
{
    public string makeNoise(Dog x)
    {
        return x.noise;
    }
}
```

`
All of those are defined in the WCF. So when I create an instance of class Dog locally, will that instance exist on my side or the server hosting the WCF service? If I'm setting 1000 instances of Dog, the latency will definitely build up. Whereas if I DON'T have to contact the server every time I make a change to my instance of Dog, then the only time I have to worry about latency is when I pass it into doSomething.makeNoise.

Comment: Please explain more what "*pass in an instance of a class that will possibly be defined in the WCF to the necessary WCF function*" means. Possible show a code example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host **creates** a new instance of the service class for each request, if you're using the default *per-call* instantiation method (which is the recommended way).

So either this is the **IIS** server which hosting your WCF service that creates an instance of your service class, or it is the `ServiceHost` instance that you've created inside your own self-hosting setup (a console app, a Windows service etc.).

The service class instance is used to handle your request - execute the appropriate method on the service class, send back any results - and then it's disposed again.

There's also the **per-session** mode in which case (assuming the binding you've chosen support sessions) your first call will create a service-class instance, and then your subsequent calls will go to the same, already created instance (until timeouts come into play etc.).

And there's also the **singleton** mode, where you have a single instance of the service class that handles all requests - this is however rather tricky to get right in terms of programming, and "challenged" in terms of scalability and performance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to host your WCF service on a public available server (for example IIS). Successful hosting will provide you with a link for the svc file. Clicking on that will give you a link ending in `singleWsdl`. You need to copy that link. On your client side, the one that requires a reference to the WCF, you will need to Add Service Reference and pass that link. This will generate proxy code with `Client` objects that you can use to access your WCF `ServiceOperation` methods.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you should have three projects. A website project to host the actual site. A WCF project to host your services. And finally a shared project, which should contain the classes you are concerned with (the models).

Both the website and wcf projects should reference the shared project, this way they both know how the models look.

The wcf project should return serialzed models as json objects, which I usually do by referencing Newtonsoft.Json.

Your website project should expect this json, and deserialize them, also using Newtonsoft.Json. This is why your class (model) should exist in the shared project, so you can use the same class on both sides of your service call.